# After upgrade to Magento2.2, error "Base table or view not found"

Tags: database, magento2.2

How can I fix this ??

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'mydatabase.mg_catalogsearch_fulltext_cl' doesn't exist, query was:
>   UPDATE `catalog_product_entity` SET `attribute_set_id` = ?, `type_id`
>   = ?, `sku` = ?, `has_options` = ?, `required_options` = ?, `created_at` = ?, `updated_at` = ? WHERE (entity_id = '3')

Both **catalog_product_entity** table and **catalogsearch_fulltext_cl** are there-
But I am not sure why there is prefix ***mg_*** in the error message above.

Comment: Check your database I think **catalog_product_entity** table is missing. if table is missing create table and reindex

Comment: ok. I will try. How many columns should I give for this table? Seven?

Comment: I actually found that catalog_product_entity exists. So what else should I do?

Comment: did you fix this?